# Returning a Bad Request while setting up mock repository in an ASP.NET web api controller for a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing unit tests for my ASP.NET core web API controllers.
For one specific unit test I am trying to post a movie and checking whether a movie with the name already exists and if it does it returns a bad request. The API works properly but I am having issues with writing the unit test.

My controller code for the post request-

```
        [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddMovie(MovieForDetailedDto movieForDetailedDto)
    { 
        if (await _repo.MovieExists(movieForDetailedDto.ATitle))
            return BadRequest("movie already exists");

        else if(!ModelState.IsValid || movieForDetailedDto.ATitle == null || movieForDetailedDto.APrice == null || movieForDetailedDto.AMovieDescription ==null)
        {
            return BadRequest("movie details not valid");
        }

        var movieToCreate = _mapper.Map<TblMovie>(movieForDetailedDto);

        var createdMovie = await _repo.AddMovie(movieToCreate);

        return Ok(createdMovie);
    }
```

The test I am writing-

```
        [Test]
    public async Task GivenAValidMovie_WhenIPostANewMovieWithExistingName_ThenItReturnsbadRequest()
    {
        getMoviesHelper getMoviesHelper = new getMoviesHelper();
        List<TblMovie> movieList = getMoviesHelper.getMovieFromList();
        _mockMovieRepository = new Mock<IMovieRepository>();
        _mockMovieMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
        _mockMovieMapper.Setup(mapper => mapper.Map<TblMovie>(It.IsAny<MovieForDetailedDto>()))
                .Returns(new TblMovie());
        _mockMovieRepository.Setup(repo => repo.AddMovie(It.IsAny<TblMovie>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(BadRequest());
        _moviesController = new MoviesController(_mockMovieRepository.Object, _mockMovieMapper.Object);
        var tblMovie = await _moviesController.AddMovie(new MovieForDetailedDto
        {
            AMovieId = 3,
            ATitle = "Big Hero 6",
            AMovieDescription = "An action comedy adventure about brilliant robotics prodigy Hiro Hamada, who finds himself in the grips of a criminal plot that threatens to destroy the fast-paced, high-tech city of San Fransokyo. With the help of his closest companion-a robot named Baymax-Hiro joins forces with a reluctant team of first-time crime fighters on a mission to save their city.",
            ADuration = "105 min",
            APrice = "10",
            APurchasePrice = "25",
            ARating = 5,
            AImageLink = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/Big_Hero_6_%28film%29_poster.jpg",
            ATrailerLink = "//www.youtube.com/embed/z3biFxZIJOQ",
            AGenre = "Comedy",
            AWideImage = "https://github.com/tushar23091998/MovieRentalApp-FrontEnd/blob/master/src/app/images/bighero6.jpg?raw=true"
        });
        Assert.IsInstanceOf<BadRequestObjectResult>(tblMovie);

    }
```

Not sure on how I should write the _mockMovieRepository setup line such that it returns a bad request.?

the function I am using to populate a list for testing purposes.

```
        public List<TblMovie> getMovieFromList()
    {
        var movies = new List<TblMovie>();
        movies.Add(new TblMovie()
        {
            AMovieId = 2,
            ATitle = "Big Hero 6",
            AMovieDescription = "An action comedy adventure about brilliant robotics prodigy Hiro Hamada, who finds himself in the grips of a criminal plot that threatens to destroy the fast-paced, high-tech city of San Fransokyo. With the help of his closest companion-a robot named Baymax-Hiro joins forces with a reluctant team of first-time crime fighters on a mission to save their city.",
            ADuration = "105 min",
            APrice = "10",
            APurchasePrice = "25",
            ARating = 5,
            AImageLink = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/Big_Hero_6_%28film%29_poster.jpg",
            ATrailerLink = "//www.youtube.com/embed/z3biFxZIJOQ",
            AGenre = "Comedy",
            AWideImage = "https://github.com/tushar23091998/MovieRentalApp-FrontEnd/blob/master/src/app/images/bighero6.jpg?raw=true"
        });
```

}

How should I go on about writing this function too-

```
        public TblMovie movieByNameExists(TblMovie tMovie)
    {
        var movies = getMovieFromList();
        foreach (TblMovie tblMovie in movies)
        {
            if (tblMovie.ATitle == tMovie.ATitle)
            {
                //return "movie already exists";
                // How do I return a BAD REQUEST HERE;

            }
        }
        return tMovie;
    }
```

THANKS FOR YOUR TIME. I am very new to unit testing so apologies if I am asking something too obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test that case, you can just set your mock to return `true` for `MovieExists` no matter what is the input.

```
_mockMovieRepository.Setup(r => r.MovieExists(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(true);
```

So it'll only simulate the case when the given movie is already in your repo (without reproducing the exact same logic of the existence check, that's for the repo tests), which is enough from the perspective of a controller test.

Your controller will return the `BadRequest` properly as expected, so you don't need to produce a fake result.